# Android :How to perform Next/Previous data details from listview items

Tags: android, listview, uibutton

i wanna show the details data from listviews android, i did it... but the problem is, i don't know how to make a function to show the next/previous detail data by clicking the next/previous button based on listview data.

this is my first activity

```
    String[] values = new String[] { "Android Example ListActivity", "Adapter implementation", "Simple List View With ListActivity",
          "ListActivity Android", "Android Example", "ListActivity Source Code", "ListView ListActivity Array Adapter", "Android Example ListActivity" };
    // Binding Array to ListAdapter
    this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, values));

    ListView lv = getListView();

    // listening to single list item on click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
      public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
          int position, long id) {

          // selected item 
          String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

          // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
          Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
          // sending data to new activity
          intent .putExtra("product", product);
          intent.putExtra("pos",position);
          startActivity(intent);
      }
    });
}
```

}

this is my second  activity where i have detail i want to put two button next and previous from these two button i want to handle my listview data

```
    TextView txtProduct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.product_label);

    Intent intent = getIntent();
    // getting attached intent data
    String product = getIntent().getStringExtra("product");
    int position=getIntent().getIntExtra("pos", 1);
    // displaying selected product name
    txtProduct.setText(" \n"+position+"  \n" +product);
    }
```

Comment: Rather passing single product info pass array of product and pos which currently shown index of array.

Answer (score 0):

```
//try this way
 String[] values = new String[] { "Android Example ListActivity", "Adapter implementation", "Simple List View With ListActivity",
                "ListActivity Android", "Android Example", "ListActivity Source Code", "ListView ListActivity Array Adapter", "Android Example ListActivity" };
        // Binding Array to ListAdapter
        this.setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.label, values));

        ListView lv = getListView();

        // listening to single list item on click
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {

                // selected item
                String product = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();

                // Launching new Activity on selecting single List Item
                Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), SingleListItem.class);
                // sending data to new activity
                intent.putExtra("products", values);
                intent.putExtra("pos",position);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });



        Intent intent = getIntent();
        // getting attached intent data
        String[] product = getIntent().getStringArrayExtra("product");
        int position=getIntent().getIntExtra("pos", 1);
```